# how to read maximum version content from text file

Tags: shell

How to read maximum version content from the below test.text file.

I should get `CMT_AH-DEV-600-V2` if pass input string is `CMT_AH-DEV-600`.

If I pass `CMT_AH-PROD-600` I should get `CMT_AH-PROD-600-V3`.

test.txt

```
CMT_AH-DEV-600-V1
CMT_AH-DEV-600-V2
CMT_AH-PROD-600-V1
CMT_AH-PROD-600-V2
CMT_AH-PROD-600-V3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try piping `grep` to find appropriate rows, `sort` to put them in appropriate order and finally `head` or `last` (depending on the order chosen) to extract the desired row.